# X9C103 10k digital potentiometer with LM317 0 - 20 V DC voltage source

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, lm317, digital-potentiometer

I need some help about my current project. I am trying to do a voltage source which can be controlled remotely (0 - 20 V). I am using LM317T for this project. I examined the LM317T datasheet and designed a circuit for a 10k potentiometer.

[image]

After setting up the circuit, I tried the circuit with the analog 10k potentiometer and the results were fine. (I get 1.25 V to 19.5 V). After that I have tried to control X9C103 with Arduino UNO and again the results were fine. Here the codes.

```
#include <FastX9CXXX.h>
#define X9_CS_PIN 3
#define X9_UD_PIN 4
#define X9_INC_PIN 5

FastX9C103 Potentiometer;
String readString = "";


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("ESOGU Uzaktan Laboratuvar"));
  Serial.print(F("Digital Potentiometer Application..."));
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  //Potentiometer.Begin();
  Potentiometer.Setup(X9_CS_PIN, X9_UD_PIN, X9_INC_PIN);
  Serial.println(F(" Completed."));

 }

void loop() {
  //Potentiometer.JumpToStep(random(100));
  Serial.print(F("Potentiometer (%): "));
  Serial.print(Potentiometer.GetStep(), DEC);
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);    // wait for a second

     if (Serial.available() > 0) {
       readString="";
       while (Serial.available()) { // gelen komutu alıyoruz
       char c = (char)Serial.read();
       readString += c;
     }
     Potentiometer.JumpToStep(readString.toInt());
     }
 }
```

But after implementing digital potentiometer to my circuit. I didn't get the results that I want. I got 1.5 V to 7 V. The circuit is working perfectly fine with analog 10k potentiometer but not with 10k digital potentiometer. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You need to show your schematic for the digital control version. You should add in a link for the digital pot datasheet you are using too. To get 20 V out of the LM317 your digital pot would have to be able to withstand 20 - 1.25 = 18. 75 V on the ADJ pin. Can it?

Comment: To understand my previous comment better, measure the voltage on the LM317 ADJ pin with your analog pot at maximum R.

Comment: How much current does your output need to support?

Comment: And what is your input voltage?

Comment: And how important is it that the minimum output voltage get right down to 0? Many adjustable regulators have a minimum above one volt.

Comment: Input voltage is DC 24 V and I am using a adapter that gives me 24 V and up to 4A. Its okay that my minumum output around 1 V since this is a student project. https://ibb.co/nghQfnb  this is my shematic for my circuit. I am using the upside circuit. Also there is a note under the shematic that didn't seen in the SS.                ''Full output current not available at high input-output voltages
*The 10 μF capacitors are optional to improve ripple rejection''

Comment: I am kind of new to the electronics generally I am interested in high voltage. I just couldn't figure out why my digital pot is not working well like analog pot works. I can control it with Arduino on a breadboard and get the results i wanted, but in circuit it just won't work. Its really hard to find instruments such as digital pots, i searched for it and all i can find is X9C103 available. If the problem in the circuit is caused by X9C103 I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: The datasheet of an LM317 shows 240 ohms for the more expensive LM117 but says the resistor between the output and ADJ pin on an LM317 should be 120 ohms and the circuit you found also has 120 ohms. But your resistor is wrong at 700 ohms!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum voltage on the digital pot resistive elements is +5V, as specified in the X9C103 [datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/x9c102-x9c103-x9c104-x9c503-datasheet?language=en?language=en).

There are other digital pots which can deal with higher voltages, but also keep in mind the minimum load current on the LM317, which may be too much for a digital pot if you try to use the resistive divider for that purpose.

Edit:

One way to do something similar to what you are asking for is this:

[image]

The LM358 amplifies the voltage from the digital pot by a factor of 5. The output voltage is thus \$\alpha \cdot 25V + 1.25V\$ where \$0 \le\alpha\le 1 \$ is the digital pot setting. The minimum setting will be somewhere around 2V.

R4/U4/Q1/R1 form a simple 10mA (roughly) constant current sink to provide minimum load on the regulator down to about 2V out.

You may want to adjust the values to get exactly what you are looking for. In this case a pot setting of 0.35 yields an op-amp output of 8.75V and therefore an output voltage of 10V. The digital pot is being used as a voltage divider rather than a rheostat, which is what it does best.

Note a slightly subtle difference between the two circuits. In the case of using a digital pot directly with the LM317 the bandgap reference within the LM317 is what determines the output voltage (modulo the resistor ratios etc.), however in the above circuit, most of the output voltage is contributed by the 5V, so it would be important to have that relatively stable and accurate (and perhaps use a separate reference or regulator). You could use a TL431 and a couple of resistors, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean that X9C103 won't suit for my design and I should try with another digital pot? It basically a voltage divider with changing resistor values for changing the output voltage but when digital pot involves it kind of get messy.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The X9C103 is suitable for output voltages as high as 6.25V only, since the ADJ terminal is Vout - 1.25V.  In practice you'd probably want to stay a bit lower than that.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your precious answer. Is there anyway to solve this problem with X9C103 like adding output a off-set or something like that or is it just impossible with X9C103 ?

Comment: See above edit. It's possible but a bit more complex, and with some caveats.

Answer (score 0):

If you can insert an inverting open collector , you can modulate the current in feedback resistor changed to 220 Ohm or so then it may function better with a minimum load current at low V.

Also I would reduce the Vadj cap greatly as this suppresses step load feedback response, to about a 10kHz LPF.

On the other hand, I don’t know how your random(100) works with the same seed or not, so I would change the Vadj RC time constant to 10ms and reduce the delay to 50ms and then do 2k or more cycles, if it is a s/w bug.